# File is not uploaded to firebase storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

Update: Smaller files (< 1 MB) seems to work fine.

---

I'm trying to upload a file to Firebase Storage from a flutter application, but the file is not uploaded, and uploadTask.onComplete finishes immediately. I get no errors until i try to get the URL with `return (await storageRef.getDownloadURL());`.

Here is the relevant code:

```dart
_uploadFile(file) async {
    String fileName = DateFormat('yy-MM-ddTH:mm:s').format(DateTime.now()).toString() + file.split('/').last;
    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(File(file));
    await uploadTask.onComplete;
    return (await storageRef.getDownloadURL());
  }
```

The error:

```
I/flutter (20165): PlatformException(download_error, Object does not exist at location., null)
E/flutter (20165): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(download_error, Object does not exist at location., null)
E/flutter (20165): #0      _AddNewsState._uploadFile (package:ny_skolapp/add_news.dart:39:7)
E/flutter (20165): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20165): #1      _AddNewsState._uploadNews (package:ny_skolapp/add_news.dart:49:25)
E/flutter (20165): #2      _AddNewsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:ny_skolapp/add_news.dart:329:31)
E/flutter (20165): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
E/flutter (20165): #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
E/flutter (20165): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (20165): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
E/flutter (20165): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
E/flutter (20165): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:199:7)
E/flutter (20165): #9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:467:9)
E/flutter (20165): #10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
E/flutter (20165): #11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:117:9)
E/flutter (20165): #12     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter (20165): #13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:115:18)
E/flutter (20165): #14     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:7)
E/flutter (20165): #15     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter (20165): #16     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (20165): #17     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (20165): #18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (20165): #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (20165): #20     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter (20165): #21     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (20165): #22     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (20165): #23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
E/flutter (20165): #24     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)
E/flutter (20165):
```

The code that calls _uploadFile(file) is the following:

```dart
_uploadNews() async {
    setState(() {
      _uploading = true;
    });
    if (_img != null) {
      if (!_img.contains('http')) {
        _imgUrl = await _uploadFile(_img);
      }else{
        _imgUrl = _img;
      }
    }
    if (_file.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < _file.length; i++) {
        if (!_file[i].contains('http')) {
          _fileUrl.add(await _uploadFile(_file[i]));
        }else{
          _fileUrl.add(_file[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('news')
        .document('$_title ${DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd  kk:mm').format(DateTime.now())}')
        .setData({
      'title': _title,
      'content': _content ?? '',
      'time': Timestamp.now(),
      'img': _imgUrl ?? '',
      'files': _fileUrl ?? [],
      'fileNames': _fileName ?? [],
    });
    setState(() {
      _uploading = false;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

`_uploadNews(_img)` and `_uploadNews(_file)` has the same problem.

And _img and _file are set with two different buttons with the following code in `onPressed`:

```dart
_img = await FilePicker.getFilePath(type: FileType.ANY);
```

and

```dart
_file.add(await FilePicker.getFilePath(type: FileType.ANY));
```

`file` comes from `FilePicker.getFilePath(type: FileType.ANY)` and I don't get an error about that, so I know that the file exists.

Comment: There are many ways to do that. You can follow these examples:  https://config9.com/apps/firebase/get-download-url-from-firebase-storage-in-flutter/

Comment: As far as I can see here, your code isn't checking for errors at all. What do you think will happen here if the upload fails? How would you know?

Comment: But I would still see an error in the terminal when running, wouldn't I? I tried try / catch and `.catchError()` without luck. Or is there an other way to chech for errors i this case? Also, an update: Smaller files ( < 1 MB) seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you say that you get an error when using `return (await storageRef.getDownloadURL());` can you precise which error it is.

Then you can try a code like this to upload a file and catch error :

```dart
Future<String> _uploadFile(String filePath) async {
   try {
      final String fileName = DateFormat('yy-MM-ddTH:mm:s').format(DateTime.now()).toString() + filePath.split('/').last;
      final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
      final StorageUploadTask task = storageRef.putFile(File(filePath));
      return await (await task.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
   } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      throw error.toString();
   }
}
```

I've used code similar to this one and it always worked until now.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the error message. I tried your exact code, but still got the same error. I have updated my original post.

Comment: Could you also show the part of your code where you call `_uploadFile(file)`